# What are the other types of database architectures?

Tags: oracle, database-design

Oracle, for example has a typical client server architecture, and a memory cache (SGA) with some background processes.

This is one way of designing a database. Are there databases out there which have been designed fundamentally in different ways than this?

Comment: Why do you say Oracle is "client server"?

Comment: @gbn: I did not understand your question. Oracle *is* a client server model, where a user process (client) connects to a server process (server) to do work.

Comment: In that case, aren't all RBDMS (which includes LDAP systems, mail servers etc) are client-server. How can you have otherwise?

Comment: @gbn: Yes, that is what I wanted to know - if there is any other way?

Comment: @Lazer - It might help if you told us why you are asking the question, what is your specific need? If you really intend the question to be this general, we'll need to migrate it to a better home (perhaps to programmers.se).

Comment: FWIW [sqlite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite) is not client-server in the way most RDBMSs are, and neither are other file-based dbs like [Jet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine).

Comment: @Lazer - I'm just closing this until you get back to me - we're very happy to open it up again if you edit... or can give us some direction via the comments to help you edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Most databases are client/server, although some embedded databases can be used purely like libraries, and share the application's address-space.

The server architecture can vary between databases, and differ from what you described too.  MySQL runs entirely as a single process (with multiple threads).  It does not require any OS shared memory segments or inter-process communication.